# Banking system that tracks dates and allows menu choices

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a simple banking program that allows the user to choose from a list of 4 options, and then depending on what the user chose, it will do that operation and then ask if the user wants another option. I also have to track what dates are entered, and make sure that an earlier date can't be entered. I have the user inputs set up, but I'm having a hard time finding a way to get the options to work, as well as set up the date checking. I thought about putting the options in a while loop but wasn't sure if that would work. Can anyone offer some help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define begin_amount 2000

int main(void) {
    int debit, credit, current_date, debit_sum, credit_sum, option; //initialize variables for withdrawing and depositing
    int new_date = 1;
    int x = 3;
    printf("what option do you want?\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    printf("Deposit\n");
    printf("Withdrawl\n");
    printf("Print Statement\n");
    printf("Interest\n");

    //deposits
    printf("Please enter todays date?\n"); //ask the user for today's date
    scanf("%d", &current_date);

    printf("how much do you want to credit to your account?\n"); //ask them to input how much they want to deposit
    scanf("%d", &credit);

    printf("Your new balance is %d\n", begin_amount+credit); //print their new balance

    //Withdrawls
    printf("Please enter todays date?\n"); //askt he user to enter today's date
    scanf("%d", &current_date);

    printf("how much do you want to debit to from account?\n"); //ask them how much they want to withdraw
    scanf("%d", &debit);

    printf("Your new balance is %d\n", begin_amount-debit); //print their new balance

    //counting amount of withdrawls and deposits
    printf("Please enter today's date?\n"); //ask the user to enter today's date
    scanf("%d", &current_date);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd recommend creating functions for all of the options, but if you just want a simple program then just have a while loop with a switch loop inside.
i.e.

```
while (true) { scanf("%d",&option); switch(option) { case 1: //deposit break; } };
```

Where you can treat each option as their own case.

Comment: would I then add case 2 for the statement option, and then so on and so forth?

Comment: Yes. But you don't have to call it case 1, case 2. Change the numbers to whatever you expect users to enter. Also make sure the user knows what to enter. `code`printf("1 - Deposit\n");
    printf("2 - Withdrawl\n");
    printf("3 - Print Statement\n");
    printf("4 - Interest\n");`code`

Comment: I see. Well I have them but now how do I make it so when someone chooses "deposit" for instance, then the program asks the user for a date and how much they want to deposit? Can I link it somehow to the print and scan statements I already have for the deposit part?

Comment: This is why i recommend learning functions. But all you have to do is inside the case for "deposit" scanf for date and scaf for how much they would like to deposit. But for date just look at this url: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time to find a way to not have to scan for time.